# How to regroup in django template?

Tags: django, html, django-models, django-templates, django-views

iI am new to Django how do i create a list by date?

example:

```
-26 June 2015
    {{episodio.es}}
    {{episodio.es}}
    {{episodio.es}}
-27 June 2015
    {{episodio.es}}
    {{episodio.es}}
```

Models:

```
class Episodio(models.Model):
        es = models.ForeignKey(Tvserie)
        network_USA = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null=True, blank=True)
        ultimo_episodio_data_USA = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        ultimo_episodio_numero_USA = models.CharField(max_length = 11, null=True, blank=True)
        ultimo_episodio_nome_USA = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
        prossimo_episodio_data_USA = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        prossimo_episodio_numero_USA = models.CharField(max_length = 11, null=True, blank=True)
        prossimo_episodio_nome_USA = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = "Episodi"
```

Views:

```
def calendarioengita(request):
    episodiusa = Episodio.objects.order_by('-prossimo_episodio_data_USA')
    return render_to_response('CalendarioEngIta.html',{'episodiusa':episodiusa})
```

Templates:

```
{% regroup episodio by episodio.prossimo_episodio_data_USA|date:"d F Y" as prossimo_episodio_data_USA_list %}
<ul>
{% for prossimo_episodio_data_USA in prossimo_episodio_data_USA_list %}
<li>{{ prossimo_episodio_data_USA.grupper}}
    {% for item in prossimo_episodio_data_USA.list %}
        <span style="color: black">{{item.es}}</span><br>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
{% endfor%}
</ul>
```

why is it wrong?
I used this document https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Please, translate the code in English.

Comment: try to change the context `{'episodiusa':episodiusa}` into something that reflects the data you want to display like `{episodiusa:[{'date':data1, 'episodiusas':[e1, e2, e3]}, ...  ]}

Comment: @Todor prossimo_episodio_data_USA is next_episode_date_USA

Comment: What is your current template outputting, and what are you expecting to get? I can see that you have misspelled `grouper` as `grupper` - it should be `{{ prossimo_episodio_data_USA.grouper }}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the `regroup` tag correctly. When you group in the `by` clause you should use the `field` directly instead `item.field`. Here try this:

```
{% regroup episodes by next_episode_date_USA|date:"d F Y" as next_episode_groups %}
<ul>
{% for next_episode_group in next_episode_groups %}
<li>{{ next_episode_group.grouper }}
    {% for episode in next_episode_group.list %}
        <span style="color: black">{{episode.es}}</span><br>
    {% endfor %}
</li>
{% endfor%}
</ul>
```